# Is java's toString() evaluated if you don't call it in your code?

Tags: java, performance, tostring

If you never explicitly or implicitly call a `toString()` method in your java code is there a chance it might still be evaluated by some JVM internals (or frameworks)?

The reason for asking is to understand if doing extra work in the `toString()` method of a class might have any performance impact.

The underlying use case for having the `toString()` is to make debugging and logging more comfortable, i.e. the method is only used with `DEBUG` logging level for diagnostic purposes but not in regular production mode.

Comment: If you're asking if there's a performance difference between calling toString implicitly and explicitly, the answer is no.  If you're asking whether doing extra work in toString() will cause it to use more clock cycles, of course it will.  Whether that makes any difference in your particular situation is unknowable in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: the question is about whether `toString()` might get called by something outside of my java code

Comment: Your title says "explicitly" and your question body says "explicitly *or implicitly*". What scenarios do you actually mean to specify by these qualifiers?

Comment: The only "magic" invocation of `toString()` that I can think of is when using a debugger, and even then it tends to be limited to items you view in the values view. And it shouldn't ever impact production environments. Unless you somehow call `toString()` in logging (even when log level is disabled), you should be fine.

Comment: I do call `toString()` in logging with debug level but I wrap that into `if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())`; but still, the question is whether something else than my code might be calling `toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely but given you state "JVM Internals" or "Frameworks" and not exactly which JVM implementations or what framework, it's hard to give guarantees.

A way is to find out if you have any implicit or under the hood calls by doing something nasty in the toString, like crashing, exception, logg, exit or Thread.sleep(10000) and make a test run to see if your application hits the toString. If not, there should be no performance implications since even if there is an odd case of something calling toString, it shouldn't be in the hot path.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no magic about `toString()`, it's never "magically" invoked. However, given that it's a method on `java.lang.Object`  calls to it can be hidden in many places (and if you worry about `MyExpensiveClass.toString()` then you might have to inspect all call sites to `Object.toString()`).

The most common source of calling `toString()` is logging (or its simpler smaller brother `System.out.println`):

It's very easy to "accidentally" call `toString` on an object, even if it's not neded. If you had a hypothetical `Logger.debug(myExpensiveObject)` call, then the log framework *could* (and usually does) avoid calling `toString` if its not actually logging at `DEBUG` level.

**However** if you do the very similar `Logger.debug("something is " + myExpensiveObject)` then the logging framework **can not** stop the `toString` method being called, because that happens *before* you even call the method.

So to summarize: no *magic* invocation of `toString()` will happen, but the non-magic ones can be hidden in plain sight.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` is called whenever an object needs to be converted to a string. There are cases where it's implicit. To name a few:

- Concatenating the object to a string (`"hello " + object`)
- Appending the object to a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`
- Calling `System.out.println(object)`
- Using the object in message interpolation, like `System.out.printf`, `String.format`, but also in logging like `LOGGER.debug("Hello {}", object)`

I'm guessing that you're using something like the latter - `LOGGER.debug("Hello {}", object)`. The good news is that any properly written logging framework will only perform interpolation if the given level is enabled. In this example, if the logger is using level `INFO` or higher, the interpolation is skipped. Some frameworks like SLF4J even have overloads for 1 or 2 arguments to prevent creating an array to handle the varargs call.

In case the arguments to the logger are dynamic, you can still prevent unnecessarily calculating them. The following two are mostly identical:

```
LOGGER.debug("Hello {}", object);
```

```
if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOGGER.debug("Hello {}", object.toString());
}
```

Comment: The implicit calls I mentioned in the question, and yes, I do wrap the logging statements with `isDebugEnabled()`